# Building Complex Repository with Linq Not Filtering Results Properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a generic repository form which I use Autofac to inject dependency to a WebApi 2.0 Controller. I am tyring to build a GET method which accepts a number of optional parameter to make a one stop shop for filtering results form the perspective of an Installer.

The DI for the controller is;

```
public class InstallerService : EntityService<Installer>, IInstallerService
{
    IContext _context;

public InstallerService(IContext context)
    : base(context)
{
    _context = context;
    _dbset = _context.Set<Installer>();
}
```

The WebApi controller GET method I need help is as follows;

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAppointments(
            int id,
            string policynumber = null,
            bool includearchived = false, 
            int? pagesize = null, 
            int? pageoffset = null)
        {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Installer>();

        predicate = predicate.And(x => x.ID == id);

        if (policynumber != null)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Appointments.Any(y => y.Vehicle.InsurancePolicyVehicles.Any(z => z.Policy.PolicyNumber.Contains(policynumber))));

        if (!includearchived)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Archived == false);

        var results = _Service.GetAppointments(predicate, pageoffset, pagesize);

        var filtered = from x in results
                       select new
        {
                           appointments = x.Appointments.Select(y => new
                           {
                               appointmentid = y.ID,
                               driverid = y.Driver.ID,
                               policyid = y.Vehicle.InsurancePolicyVehicles.Select(z => z.Policy.ID),
                               policynumber = y.Vehicle.InsurancePolicyVehicles.Select(z => z.Policy.PolicyNumber),
                               created = y.CreatedDate,
                               policyholder = y.Driver.PolicyHolder,
                               date = y.Date,
                               ampm = y.AmPm,
                               installer = new
                               {
                                   installerid = x.ID,
                                   name = x.Name,
                                   contact = x.Contact,
                                   qascore = x.QAScore,
                                   address1 = x.Address1,
                                   address2 = x.Address2,
                                   address3 = x.Address3,
                                   address4 = x.Address4,
                                   city = x.City,
                                   county = x.County,
                                   postcode = x.PostCode,
                                   country = x.Country,
                                   email = x.Email,
                                   web = x.Web,
                                   archived = x.Archived,
                                   numberofinstalls = x.NumberOfInstalls,
                                   numberoffailedinstalls = x.NumberOfFailedInstalls
                               },
                               device = new
                               {
                                   deviceid = y.Device.ID,
                                   iccid = y.Device.ICCID,
                                   imei = y.Device.IMEI,
                                   msisdn = y.Device.MSISDN,
                               },
                               status = y.Status,
                               archived = y.Archived
                           })
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filtered);
        if (json != "[]") 
            json = json.Replace("[{\"appointments\":", "").TrimEnd('}',']');

        return Ok(json);
    }
```

The service method is simply;

```
public List<Installer> GetAppointments(Expression<Func<Installer, bool>> predicate, int? pageSize = null, int? pageIndex = null)
        {
            var results = _context.Installers
                    .Include(x => x.Appointments)
                    .Include(x => x.Appointments.Select(y => y.Driver))
                    .Include(x => x.Appointments.Select(y => y.Vehicle))
                    .Include(x => x.Appointments.Select(y => y.Vehicle.InsurancePolicyVehicles.Select(z => z.Policy)))
                    .Include(x => x.Appointments.Select(y => y.Device))
                    .AsExpandable()
                    .Where(predicate);

            if (pageIndex != null && pageSize != null)
                results = results.Skip((pageIndex.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value);

            return results.ToList();

        }
```

I realise this is a bit odd, but unfortunately the specification states they must be able to return data from this perspective.

If I filter down based on an id, it works fine and I get the filtered list of results.

However, if i send a policy number along with an id, eithe for a partial or complete match. I get the whole result set for the id and its not filtered down based on the policy number at all.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Have you checked what sql is being executed? Try adding this line before your query and see what it produces: `_context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: Also, try adding the `.AsExpandable()` right after `.Installers` rather than after the includes.

Comment: @SimonC Thanks for the reply. I added the .AsExpandable after teh installers and as a reuslt the .Appointments array was returned as null? Sorry but where about should i place the 

_context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); 

After var results = _context.Installers.... ?